# Websphere application server - don't redirect to https

Tags: security, https, websphere

I have a WAS on my local computer installed and I am trying to integrate some custom logic with websphere business monitor.

I need to send xml messages for processing to specified rest interface.

In my code I am using jersey api for rest to simplify creating the connections.

Here is a link containing some information about this rest interface

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r2mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.bspace.620.help.api.rest.doc/apis/eventemitter/index.htm

I can send events if I use the `https://localhost:9443` url and if I "disable" ssl security on my client jvm side.

I know that someday I will need to generate the certificates and all of that, but for now I just wanted to access this interface using normal http like `http://localhost:9080`.

The thing is, if I use this URL I am getting 302 return code and I am redircted to the old one.

My question is, what do I need to change so there won't be any redirection to `https` version?

The thing I noticed is that this "interface" is not listed in `Services->Rest Services`, but there exists an application `IBM_WBM_EMITTER_SERVICES` so I was suspecting that there may be something that I need to change in this application settings so it can "accept" plain old `http` connections.